# printing a list entry dosent format correctly

Tags: python

I have a problem with this

```
def randomrecipes():
print (random.sample(listofrecipes, 1))
mainmenu()


listofrecipes = [monday, tuesday, wednsday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday]
```

the recipes is formatted like this (just ignore the Norwegian gibberish).

```
monday"""
1 l kjøttkraft /buljong eller lettsaltet vann
750 g rå potet
300 g kokt potet
3 dl byggmel
2 ss hvetemel
1 ts salt
"""
```

When I just print it, it comes out with the whitespace preserved, but from `randomrecipes` I get this:

```
['\n1 l kjøttkraft /buljong eller lettsaltet vann\n750 g rå potet\n300 g kokt potet\n3 dl byggmel\n2 ss hvetemel\n1 ts salt\n']
```

Im trying to learn by myself and is just getting started, so sorry if this is a dumb question. Thanks.

Comment: Where and how is listofrecipes defined? The definition of `random.sample` is to return a list of a certain length; that is what you have, a list consisting of a single item.

Comment: If you `print (random.sample(listofrecipes, 1)[0])` you will probably see the original formatting. The output of the list shows the list structure and newline \n characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`random.sample(iterable, k)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) which always returns a list of length `k` or in your case 1. So the object you're printing is a list of a string.

You could change the line

```
print (random.sample(listofrecipes, 1))
```

to something like

```
print(random.sample(listofrecipes,1)[0])  # note the [0]
```

That will return the *first* element in the list (which happens to be the only one).

A cleaner solution might be instead to use [`random.choice(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice). It always returns a single choice, not a list. It is effectively equivalent as the line above, but it's a little clearer.

Comment: An alternative solution that comes to mind (if you ever wanted to get 2 or more random recipes at once) would be to join them all together with a newline delimiter. Something like `'\n'.join(random.sample(listofrecipes, 2)` would print two random ones, one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

`random.sample` [returns a list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.sample), which is exactly what you're getting. This output is just how lists are formatted. If you want to extract the string from this list, do it:

```
random.sample(listofrecipes, 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `random.sample` is a list of a certain length, 1 in this instance. When you print this you are seeing the output that is generated when displaying a list, including newline `\n` characters.

```
print(random.sample(listofrecipes, 1)[0])
```

would print out the string, the first element of the list, which would reinstate the original display across several lines.